# Load File From Virtual Folder Using Delphi 2007

Tags: windows, delphi

I am trying to load the contents of a file from one of the Windows virtual folders (for example, a camera or iPhone picture folder).  Below is some sample code that I am using to play around with this:

```
procedure TfrmForm.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  Dialog: TAttachDialog;
  Enum: IEnumShellItems;
  Name: LPWSTR;
  Item: IShellItem;
  Strm: IStream;
  OStrm: TOLEStream;
  FStrm: TFileStream;
  Result: HRESULT;
  Buf: Array[0..99] Of Char;
  Read: LongInt;
begin
  Result := CoInitializeEx(Nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED Or
                                COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
  If Succeeded(Result) Then
  Begin
    Dialog := TAttachDialog.Create(Self);
    Try
      Dialog.Options := [fdoAllowMultiSelect, fdoPathMustExist,
                         fdoFileMustExist];
      Dialog.Title := 'Select Attachments';

      If Dialog.Execute(Self.Handle) Then
      Begin
        If FAILED(Dialog.ShellItems.EnumItems(Enum)) Then
          Raise Exception.Create('Could not get the list of files selected.');

        While Enum.Next(1, Item, Nil) = S_OK Do
        Begin
          If (Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, Name) = S_OK) Then
          Begin
            mResults.Lines.Add(Name);
            CoTaskMemFree(Name);
          End;

          If Item.BindToHandler(Nil, BHID_Stream, IID_IStream, Strm) = S_OK Then
          Begin
            OStrm := TOLEStream.Create(Strm);
            FStrm := TFileStream.Create('C:\Temp\Test.jpg', fmCreate);
            FStrm.CopyFrom(OStrm, OStrm.Size);
            FreeAndNil(OStrm);
            FreeAndNil(FStrm);
            Strm := Nil;
          End;

          Item := Nil;
        End;
      End;
    Finally
      FreeAndNil(Dialog);
    End;
    CoUninitialize;
  End;
end;
```

TAttachDialog is just a descendant of TCustomFileOpenDialog that exposes the ShellItems property.  In my actual application, I need a TStream object returned.  So, in this example, I am using a TFileStream top copy the source file as proof of concept that I have successfully accessed the file using a Delphi stream.  Everything works Ok until I try the FStrm.CopyFrom at which point I get a "Not Implemented" error.  What am I doing wrong with this or is there a better way entirely to do what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only time `TStream` itself raises a "not implemented" error is if neither the 32bit or 64bit version of `Seek()` are overridden in a descendant class (or one of them erroneously called the `inherited` method).  If that were true, an `EStreamError` exception is raised saying "ClassName.Seek not implemented".

`TOLEStream` does override the 32bit version of `Seek()` to call `IStream.Seek()`.  However, it does not override the `TStream.GetSize()` property getter.  So when you are reading the `OStrm.Size` value before calling `CopyFrom()`, it calls the default `TStream.GetSize()` method, which uses `Seek()` to determine the stream size - `Seek()` to get the current position, then `Seek()` again to the end of the stream, saving the result, then `Seek()` again to go back to the previous position.

So, my guess would be that the `IStream` you have obtained likely does not support random seeking so its `Seek()` method is returning `E_NOTIMPL`, which `TOLEStream.Seek()` would detect and raise an `EOleSysError` exception saying "Not implemented".

Try calling `IStream.Stat()` to get the stream size (or derive a class from `TOLEStream` and override the `GetSize()` method to call `Stat()`), and then pass the returned size to `CopyFrom()` if > 0 (if you pass `Count=0` to `CopyFrom()`, it will read the source stream's `Position` and `Size` properties, thus causing the same `Seek()` error), eg:

```
var
  ...
  Stat: STATSTG;
begin
  ...
  if Item.BindToHandler(Nil, BHID_Stream, IID_IStream, Strm) = S_OK Then
  try
    OStrm := TOLEStream.Create(Strm);
    try
      FStrm := TFileStream.Create('C:\Temp\Test.jpg', fmCreate);
      try
        OleCheck(Strm.Stat(Stat, STATFLAG_NONAME));
        if Stat.cbSize.QuadPart > 0 then
          FStrm.CopyFrom(OStrm, Stat.cbSize.QuadPart);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(FStrm);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(OStrm);
    end;
  finally
    Strm := Nil;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

The alternative would be to simply avoid `TStream.CopyFrom()` and manually copy the bytes yourself, by allocating a local buffer and then calling `OStrm.Read()` in a loop, writing each read buffer to `FStrm`, until `OStrm.Read()` reports that there is no more bytes to read:

```
var
  ...
  Buf: array[0..1023] of Byte;
  NumRead: Integer;
begin
  ...
  if Item.BindToHandler(Nil, BHID_Stream, IID_IStream, Strm) = S_OK Then
  try
    OStrm := TOLEStream.Create(Strm);
    try
      FStrm := TFileStream.Create('C:\Temp\Test.jpg', fmCreate);
      try
        repeat
          NumRead := OStrm.Read(Buf[0], SizeOf(Buf));
          if NumRead <= 0 then Break;
          FStrm.WriteBuffer(Buf[0], NumRead);
        until False;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(FStrm);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(OStrm);
    end;
  finally
    Strm := Nil;
  end;
  ...
end;
```